# Sql Server: A seemingly strange behaviour of BEGIN TRAN - COMMIT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

First create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (Id INT)
CREATE TABLE abc (Id INT)
```

Please, observe the following SQL code:

```
DELETE FROM abc
BEGIN TRAN
EXEC('
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (1),(2)
DECLARE @x INT = (SELECT Id FROM xyz)
')
INSERT INTO abc VALUES (1)
COMMIT

SELECT * FROM abc
```

Running it outputs the following error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

**And there is no result**. All as expected.

Now let us change the error to a syntax error by replacing `xyz)` with `xyz`. Here is the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'xyz'.
```

But this time there is a result:

[image]

Why? What is going on?

**EDIT**

I really apologise for a badly formulated question. The problem is not with the temporary variables. I have reworked the question to eliminate any temporary variable tables.

Comment: Because table variables do not take part in transactions?

Comment: When I run this on my machine, both times something is returned

Comment: For an in-depth analysis on the difference between temporary tables and table variables, read this on dba.stackexchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/65699. Topic "Transactions" mentions what is said in the previous comment by Ivan.

Comment: I am sorry, my question was badly formulated. It is not about the TVPs.

Comment: A rationale for the down-vote would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx

> Because table variables have limited scope and are not part of the persistent database, they are not affected by transaction rollbacks.

Comment: I am sorry, my question was badly formulated. It is not about the TVPs

Answer (score 1):

Why? What is going on?

okay ...

in first query:

```
 DECLARE @x INT = (SELECT id FROM @tmp2)
```

There is 2 values into  @tmp TABLE so you cannot insert the two values into variable so you get the following error:-

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

in second query:

```
DECLARE @x INT = (SELECT id FROM @tmp2
```

There is syntax error , you should type another `)` in the end, so you get the following error :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '@tmp2'.
```

Try the next one for retrieving one row:

```
 DECLARE @x INT = (SELECT top (1) id FROM @tmp2) -- top 1 just for test
```

Note: in both cases the returned result are as the next:

[image]